# (Java) Questions after converting Hex String to Byte Array

Tags: java, hex, byte, message

I'm trying to convert the Hex String `0280000000288B41` etc. 0x02, 0x80, 0x00, .. , 0x8B, 0x41 to byte[] array and send it to a device connected to my laptop.

I'm using 2 ways to convert them. Firstly is this method I found here:

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hex) {
        int l = hex.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[l/2];
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i += 2) {
            data[i/2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hex.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(hex.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Secondly, it's by using DatatypeConverter

```
    public static byte[] toByteArray(String s) {
        return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s);
    }
```

I have 2 similar results,

```
index: 0 value: 2
index: 1 value: -128
index: 2 value: 0
index: 3 value: 0
index: 4 value: 0
index: 5 value: 40
index: 6 value: -117
index: 7 value: 65
```

which is equivalent to:

```
2, -128, 0, 0, 0, 40, -117, 65
```

So now, I have a couple of questions. I'm sorry as I'm still learning how to program.

I understand that hexadecimal, decimal, ASCII chars etc are all representations for us programmers, and when I execute my code, it will convert all these representations into binary and send a message to the device attached to my laptop (my communications ports are all okay). I'm supposed to get a response, and although I did, it is not exactly how it turned out to be (the device led out a beeping sound but the display is supposed to show something and it didn't).

I was wondering if there is anything wrong with my code, in terms of sending a message via hexadecimal values?

In addition, why is there a negative sign for the 2nd index? (-128)? does that mean that the hex value of 80 represents -128 in byte (data type)?

Lastly, all these byte values in my byte array are converted automatically in binary (without me doing anything except to run the code for now) to the device, right?

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Your code doesn't show us how you're sending anything, so asking us if there is something wrong *in terms of sending a message* isn't helpful, we can't answer that.

Comment: @Frontear Sorry, let me rephrase I was asking if sending a message via byte array is a viable option.. I'm actually just sending a message through my COM port COM1 to a device. I'm just lacking the knowledge in the theory portion. -- for example, just by converting hexadecimal to byte[] array is sufficient? im merely sending the byte[] array through the com port to my device.